# Custom component data is not displaying inside cxOutletPos

Tags: spartacus-storefront

My Custom component data is not displaying inside cxOutletPos.
No issue with "static html code" inside cxOutletPos, It is working displaying properly.

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="cx-footer" cxOutletPos="before">
    <h1>welcome</h1>
    <app-custom-header></app-custom-header>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a Spartacus issue, as I tried your code, and in my case the custom component could also be displayed correctly in the outlet. Please refer to my test result. I am using Spartacus 2.1.0. Which version are you using?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm using 4.1.1, and cxOutletPos doesn't work.